# How do i apply scroll for long horizontal background image?

Tags: html, css, image, scroll

I have very simple html page with looong (~8000px width) horizontal panorama image.

The image is set in css as a  *background* `background-image:url('long_jpg.jpg');`.

I need just to have a scrollbar at the bottom of the page to be able just to scroll the whole background image.

How can do that with css? Can you please give any working example?

Comment: What is the element you are setting the background image for? You can just give that the width of 8000? Or just place the image itself instead of applying it to an element with CSS?

Comment: `overflow-x: scroll`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this working example http://jsfiddle.net/a9QvT/1/

```
.panorama
{
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1024px;
    background-image: url(http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0188.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set the body width to the same width as the image

```
body {
    width:8000px;
}
```

If you have any other content, you want to encapsulate all that in a div, so that the content doesn't shatter across 8000px as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't do this?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src="picture.jpg" class="bgpic" />
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 8000px;
    height: 100%;
}

.bgpic
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this...

```
body {
margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
background-image: url('long_jpg.jpg');
min-width: 8000px;
height: 100%;
}
```

but a quick warning, in terms of design and layout, people are used to pages which scroll up and down, asking them to scroll side to side will seem pretty annoting to most people. Unless you use some anchor tags and they can just click their way to specific points on the page without having the drag the scroll bar.